# Running R scripts from SSRS

Tags: r, reporting-services

Is it possible to fire off an R script (that pulls in data through an ODBC connection and makes a graph) from an SSRS report hosted on a report server?  And if so, would R need to be installed at some server level, or on each person's machine?